# Identifying a signal in logic analyzer pulse train

Tags: rs485

I'm working with an unknown RS-485 signal, possibly RS-422 with a Saleae logic analyzer. I can identify the command and response sequence but can't figure out what this "pulse train" is there for, 0xFF sequence after the 0x3F. It seems to be periodic with two different pulse widths. The pulse widths don't seem to match the pulse width of a bit. [image: Screenshot of the command and response with no glitch filtering and pulse trains visible]

Here is a close up of the "pulse train".

[image]

Comment: I fixed the title and reduced the unreasonable amount of white space that was oddly placed with one of your pictures.

Answer (score 5):

> can't figure out what this "pulse train" is there for, 0xFF sequence

Notice how that `0xFF` sequence only appears each time on *one* of the two logic analyser inputs, which you have assigned to a pair of differential signals. Here is the first one:

[image: First 0xFF sequence]

Notice that the previous byte sequence (`0xA0 0x00 0x00 0x10` etc.) is shown properly as a differential pair of signals i.e. opposite polarity on *two* logic analyser channels:

[image: Normal differential signals]

Compare those two displays. That change in the display strongly suggests that the `0xFF` sequence *may not be valid at all*, and that you may be falling into the trap of believing the logic analyser, when it tries to decode noise or other invalid signals.

If you have an oscilloscope, then it will be easy to confirm this hypothesis, by looking at the analog voltages on both wires of the RS-485 bus, when the logic analyser decodes that `0xFF` sequence on only one channel.

It is quite common, for example on a half-duplex RS-485 bus, for the bus to be "undriven" for periods of time. If the system designer did not implement "failsafe biasing" then when the bus is undriven, it is effectively an antenna and will pickup noise.

An interesting piece of evidence for this hypothesis is shown for the second `0xFF` sequence:

[image: Second 0xFF sequence]

Notice that this `0xFF` sequence appears on the top (only) logic analyser channel, and is therefore likely *invalid*, as no opposite polarity signal is displayed on the second channel except for an initial glitch (itself interesting). However that `0xFF` occurs *at the same time* as an apparently *valid* signal is shown for the lower pair of logic analyser channels - i.e. the top (undriven?) logic analyser channel may be picking-up the coupled signal coming from that second RS-485 bus, and trying to decode whatever noise it sees!

Depending on how much you know about the original system design, and how much you can change it, you may have to either ignore those invalid attempts at decoding by the logic analyser, or you could investigate adding "failsafe biasing" to each bus, to force a fixed bus state when it is undriven.

Finally: Personally, I would use a genuine RS-485 receiver for each bus, feeding into one logic analyser channel per bus, rather than connecting two logic analyser channels per bus directly to the individual RS-485 signals as you are currently doing. Those RS-485 signals swing both positive and negative, relative to the common ground. Depending on the input protection in your analyser, that might be a problem (especially the negative voltages), and/or might add unexpected loading to the RS-485 bus. It is also possible to have valid RS-485 voltages which the analyser will not detect as valid *logic levels* and therefore not display. Again, using a genuine RS-485 receiver does not have that problem.

---

**Update:** New oscilloscope screenshot when logic analyser decodes `0xFF`:

[image: Interference signal on oscilloscope]

We can see that:

- Approximately equal amplitude on both wires, so not valid RS-485.
- Both signals seem to idle close to Gnd, which suggests the system designer has not implemented "failsafe biasing" using resistors on the signal lines (since then the idle voltages for the two signals would be different by at least 200 mV). To improve the accuracy when trying to read only valid data on that bus, while minimising changes and their possible side-effects, trying a modern RS-485 receiver with built-in failsafe biasing would be a sensible test.
- Frequency looks to be ~120 Hz so something related to mains power seems a likely source (not surprising for an antenna in a country with 60 Hz mains supply).
- This low frequency explains why the bit length doesn't match the RS-485 data rate (which looks like 9600 bps in your example) during valid data transfers.
- Amplitude up to around +0.7 V, so depending on the exact logic thresholds used by the logic analyser, it's not a surprise that the analyser believes it is detecting a change of logic levels, and hence something that it should decode.

This is exactly the trap that I have seen many times. Until you have used an oscilloscope to look at, and validate, the signal being used by a logic analyser, you cannot trust that what the logic analyser "decodes" is what is actually happening "on the wire".

A genuine RS-485 receiver should not report any output, with those voltages on an RS-485 interface, as it isn't valid RS-485. That would be yet another advantage of using a genuine receiver.

Comment: Regarding the noise on the line, I had some suspicions about it being glitching or the logic analyzer misinterpreting the line so I enabled the glitch filter in the Logic software. One issue I don't understand is why the pulses of the glitches are larger then the pulses of the a single bit in the command in some instances.

Comment: wrt: the bus being an antenna, isn't that why it's using an ethernet cable? or is that just to reduce cross talk? Also, we have no real insight into the system design, we're trying to reverse engineering a device that uses this protocol to send and rec commands.

Comment: @user3577138 *"I enabled the glitch filter in the Logic software"* Depending on the length of pulses that filter suppresses, it won't help if the noise pulses are longer. *"why the pulses of the glitches are larger then the pulses of the a single bit"* I doubt they are valid bits, so stop comparing their length :-) *"isn't that why it's using an ethernet cable"* Using Ethernet cable (I assume UTP) doesn't prevent the cable acting like an antenna *especially when the RS-485 bus is undriven* (which is my main hypothesis). Have you viewed (or can you view) the RS-485 buses using an oscilloscope?

Comment: I can hook up an oscope tomorrow and I'll post my results.

Comment: [screen shot of the oscope on Rx+ and RX-](http://imgur.com/a/TQV4W)

Comment: @user3577138 - Thanks, I've updated my answer with an analysis of that screenshot. No surprise, it is exactly the type of external interference expected on a wire which is undriven and therefore acting as an antenna :-) Why not add a genuine RS-485 receiver IC to your monitoring setup (hopefully you can steal a few mA of power from somewhere) and feed its output into a spare channel on your logic analyser. Then you can confirm *that* channel of the logic analyser only shows the *valid* RS-485 data, and not those spurious `0xFF` sequences. Hope that helps!

Comment: The signal does have a 120Hz frequency. Why would it be 120Hz and not 60Hz? The only thing I can think of is harmonics and how could you determine given the images that the signal is transmitting with 9600 baud?

Comment: I have the logic threshold of the saleae logic analyzer at 3.3v+ but the amplitude of the signal on the oscope is at about 1V. One thing to note is that the pulse train is consistent on the RX- bus. Why would that be?

Comment: @user3577138 - In short: **120Hz** - Examples like bridge-rectified mains. **different bit widths** - Analyser may be digitising either (a) 120Hz interference or (b) coupled signal from the *other* RS-485 bus which I noticed (although no scope trace provided of *this* interference) FYI analyser may not show such interference as being same frequency as original signal. If you want to research *that* interference, capture a scope trace of it and analyse waveform (amplitude, shape, frequency). **pulse train is consistent on the RX- bus.** I don't understand what you mean. More explanation needed.

Answer (score 0):

When RS-485 signals appear to be mismatched , i.e. not complementary that indicates a signal error, perhaps after end of message.

It is possible to create a bit error flag in logic with sample counts using XOR if you wanted to filter this .

It becomes visibly apparent when glitches only occur on 1 line at a time.

Spectral analysis or inverse timing will reveal that COmmon Mode noise is often caused by inappropriate shielding at both ends from line noise or unbalanced cables with SMPS noise.  Sometimes a Ferrite CM choke or SMD CM transformer is essential to improve the CMRR by 30dB.  Low frequency noise probably due to ground loops on the shield which should never be earth grounded at both ends, only at one end and the a cap with a few nF to the other end for RF but not line noise.

Unless you are going full duplex, there is no need to shut off the drivers. and if you want to bias it in one logic complementary level then 10k is better than open circuit and won't impair the signal when active with 100~220 Ohm differential load. depending on STP or UTP.